# Вырезается кусок значения из переменной

Tags: php

Решаю банальную задачу - отправка почты средствами php.

Код обработки формы таков:

```
if((isset($_POST['username'])&&
   $_POST['username']!='')&&
   (isset($_POST['email'])&&
   $_POST['email']!=''))
   {
       //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они
       $to = 'recepient@example.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
       $subject = 'Заявка с сайта example.com'; 
       $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Имя заказчика: '.$_POST['username'].'</p>
                        <p>Его телефон: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
                        <p>Обращение было сделано с сайта example.com</p>                        
                    </body>
                </html>'; 
       $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8; \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
       $headers.= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n"; 
       $headers.= "Bcc: birthday-archive@example.com\r\n"; 
       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail

       print_r($_POST);
       print($headers);
   }
```

Вывод POST дает такой результат:

> Array ( [email] => int@mail.ru [username] => Andrey25 )
>   Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8;
>   From: Birthday Reminder
>   Bcc: birthday-archive@example.com

Словно, все есть кроме самого почтового ящика, который я просто вывожу на экран. Объясните мне, что эта за такие "чудеса" техники тут?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$email = explode('@', $_POST['email']);

$message = '...
<p>Его телефон: '.$email[0].'@'.$email[1].'</p>
...';
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не видите почтового ящика  потому что смотрите результат в браузере. а браузер принимает его за HTML-тег и не отображает. Посмотрите исходный код страницы и увидите полный вывод

В своих проектах использовал SwiftMailer http://swiftmailer.org/. Почта сайта висела на гугл-почте, подключался и отправлял все письма с неё. Возможно письма и отправляются, только сейчас в почтовых сервисах есть проверка какая-то на подлинность домена или как-то так, что письма с локальных доменов не отправляются и не принимаются. Попробуйте подключаться к сушествующему почтовому ящику и с него отправлять используя SwiftMailer

Comment: Это хорошо бы, только вот отправка письма тоже не прокатывала... Задержки с почтой, или что-то другое. И без обрамлений тоже не выводит кстати у меня. Так что тут дело не в тегах.

Comment: В своих проектах использовал SwiftMailer http://swiftmailer.org/. Почта сайта висела на гугл-почте, подключался и отправлял все письма с неё. Возможно письма и отправляются, только сейчас в почтовых сервисах есть проверка какая-то на подлинность домена или как-то так, что письма с локальных доменов не отправляются и не принимаются. Попробуйте подключаться к сушествующему почтовому ящику и с него отправлять используя SwiftMailer